# How do i find number of weeks from start date to end of the current week in Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have query in access `db` which looks like this:-

```
IIf(Weekday([HiredDate])=7,[HiredDate],[HiredDate]-Weekday([HiredDate])) AS TrainingStart, 
Date()+6-Weekday(Date()) AS EndOfWeek, 
DateDiff("ww",[TrainingStart],[EndOfWeek]) AS WeekNumber,
```

How do I write query with same logic in my `oracle`.

Here is what I have written and I do not think it is right.

```
SELECT Name, HiredDate, 
(CASE WHEN (to_char(to_date(HiredDate), 'd') = 7) THEN HiredDate ELSE (HiredDate - to_char(to_date(HiredDate), 'd')) END) as TraingStart, 
(CURRENT_DATE + (6 - to_char(to_date(CURRENT_DATE), 'd'))) as EndDate,
(To_Number(to_char(to_date((CURRENT_DATE + (6 - to_char(to_date(CURRENT_DATE), 'd')))),'WW')) - To_number(to_char(to_date((HiredDate - to_char(to_date(HiredDate), 'd'))),'WW')) +1) as WEEKNUMBER 
FROM employee;
```

Comment: I already forgot almost everything I ever knew about Access. I might be able to help you with Oracle, but you must explain the problem to me in plain English, not by reference to code in a different SQL dialect, which I do not know. I assume that explaining the problem in English will not be very difficult.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct? Did you test it? Did you consult relevant Oracle documentation?

Comment: Having `6 - to_char(...` is always suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use something like following to count weeks as Change in the year of the start and end date can affect my result.

You can try the following:

```
WITH DATE_RANGE AS (
    SELECT
        DATE '2019-12-01' START_DATE,
        DATE '2020-02-26' END_DATE
    FROM
        DUAL
)
SELECT
    COUNT(LEVEL) AS NUMBER_OF_WEEKS
--    , LEVEL   "Week",
--    TRUNC(START_DATE +(7 *(LEVEL - 1)), 'IW') AS START_OF_THE_WEEK,
--    TRUNC(START_DATE +(7 *(LEVEL - 1)), 'IW') + 6 AS END_OF_THE_WEEK,
--    TO_CHAR(START_DATE +(7 *(LEVEL - 1)), 'IW') WEEK_NUMBER
FROM
    DATE_RANGE
CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= ( TRUNC(END_DATE, 'IW') - TRUNC(START_DATE, 'IW') ) / 7 + 1;

Output:

NUMBER_OF_WEEKS
---------------
             14
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find number of weeks between 2 dates.

```
SELECT (trunc(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'd')-trunc(TO_DATE(HIRED_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'd'))/7
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Running `to_date()` on a value which is already a **DATE** is usually a bad idea. You better may use `trunc()`